# Having trouble setting up xip.io with MAMP Pro

Tags: mamp

I am having a lot of trouble setting xip.io for MAMP Pro on OS X Lion. I am doing this so I can run Adobe Shadow locally.

I have read through 2 tutorials:

http://blogs.adobe.com/shadow/2012/06/19/shadow-xip-io-virtual-hosts-workflow-simplified/

http://www.thenerdary.net/post/24695946158/xip-io-and-apache-serveralias/

done what they have both said and still can't seem to get it fully working.

All I get is a page saying "It works!" but I can't get it to display the index.php page that resides in that folder.

Has anyone else set this up using the same environment or know of a good (more in depth) tutorial that could help ..?

Many thanks, Jack

Comment: The "It works!" page is from the built-in Apache of Mac OS X. Switch off web sharing in the preferences of Mac OS X and start the servers of MAMP PRO again.

Comment: YES!!! It worked, can't believe I missed that :)

Thank you